# Setting Number of Fetch Using ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

I'm using `ASIHTTPRequest` to fetch data from an Google Feed API.

Right now it is only fetching 5 latest posts but can I change this to a larger number?

Comment: That depend on the API you're using. Can you post the URL of your query?

Comment: I'm using the Google Feed API, this is my query: `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?q=http://feeds.feedburner.com/TechCrunch&v=1.0"];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [JSON Developer's Guide for the Google Feed API:](http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/apis/feed/v1/jsondevguide.html#request_format)

You have to use the parameter `num` to specify the number of entries.

Example query:

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?q=http://feeds.feedburner.com/TechCrunch&v=1.0&num=100

That returns 100 entries.